# Active Directory Authentication without using Windows

Tags: python, asp.net, active-directory

I want to implement a python script that login my university's file sharing platform which uses ASP.NET's Active Directory. I searched some but I found a solution which requires pywin32 for [pyad](https://github.com/zakird/pyad) module. I want to run this script my Linux server but pywin32 requires Windows API. Are there any solution to authenticate Active Directory pages without using Windows?

Comment: Take a look at [this article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.12.linux.aspx)

Comment: thanks. I will look that.